# intl-tel-input dropdown not working on mobile browser

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, mobile-website, intl-tel-input

I am using intl-tel-input [library](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) for international telephone dropdown selection.

[image]

When opening the app on web browser, country flags are coming as expected with proper styling, but it comes like above screenshot in mobile browser. I have added the flag css like

`background-image: url("../images/flags@2x.png");`

Library's live sample is [here](https://intl-tel-input.com/). Any clue?

--------------------- Edit ---------------------

I am using International Telephone Input v9.0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the CSS files of the lib and many other options, finally library update resolved the issue.

I replaced the older version library with latest [Release v12.1.2](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input). And now it looks like below in mobile device.

[image]

Comment: I've had the same exact symptom as you. For me it was a typo in my html when including the css (`media="scree"` instead of `media="screen"`). The tricky part was it triggerd no error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't problem with lib version, but z-index on dropdown div. So check css first, then try other solutions.